# How to do FourierSeries of this function?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I try to do FourierSeries in Mathematica but somehow this code runs forever...

Could someone help? Thank you.

`FourierSeries[(a^2 b Sin[x])/(  b^2 (Cos[x])^2 + a^2 (Sin[x])^2 )^(3/2),x,2]`

Answer (score 2):

First, this is an odd function, so `FourierSeries` is `FourierSinSeries`.
Second, up to constant multipliers , the following does the job.

```
FourierSinSeries[(Sin[x])/(1 + c^2 (Sin[x])^2)^(3/2), x, 2, Assumptions -> c > 0]
```

> `(1/\[Pi])2 ((-EllipticE[-c^2] + (1 + c^2) EllipticK[-c^2])/( c^2 + c^4) + (-EllipticE[c^2/(1 + c^2)] +  EllipticK[c^2/(1 + c^2)])/(c^2 Sqrt[1 + c^2])) Sin[x]`

and/or

```
FourierSinSeries[(Sin[x])/(1 + c^2 (Cos[x])^2)^(3/2), x, 2, Assumptions -> c > 0]
```

> `(1/(c^2 \[Pi]))2 (EllipticE[-c^2] -  EllipticK[-c^2] + ((1 + c^2) EllipticE[c^2/(1 + c^2)] -  EllipticK[c^2/(1 + c^2)])/Sqrt[1 + c^2]) Sin[x]`

Comment: Just to compare. The code of Maple `with(OrthogonalExpansions):

assuming([FourierSeries(sin(x)/(1+c^2*sin(x)^2)^(3/2), x = -Pi .. Pi, 2)], [c > 0]);` performs $${\frac {\sin \left( x \right) }{\pi} \left( 4\,{\frac {1}{ \left( {c}^
{2}+1 \right) ^{3/2}}{\it EllipticK} \left( {\frac {c}{\sqrt {{c}^{2}+
1}}} \right) }+4\,{\frac {1}{ \left( {c}^{2}+1 \right) ^{3/2}{c}^{2}}{
\it EllipticK} \left( {\frac {c}{\sqrt {{c}^{2}+1}}} \right) }-4\,{
\frac {1}{\sqrt {{c}^{2}+1}{c}^{2}}{\it EllipticE} \left( {\frac {c}{
\sqrt {{c}^{2}+1}}} \right) } \right) }
 .$$
`